# How to prove that a sequence $f_{n} \in L^{1}$?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-measure, banach-spaces, sequence-of-function

I'm trying to studying Banach and Hilbert spaces.

I'm interested to clearly understand when a sequence of functions $f_{n}$ begin to a Banach space ($L^{1}$) or to a Hilbert space ($L^{2}$).

I think that $f_{n}$ must be measurable and integrable, but I'm asking to you a rigorous method to prove that and why we do in such way.

EDIT:
An exemple for $f_n$ is
$$f_{n}=\frac{2x^{3}}{n+x^{4}}$$
with $n\ge1$ and $x \in [0+\infty)$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: By definition, a necessary condition to be in $L^p$ is to be measurable. A sequence is in $L^1$ if $f_n\in L^1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have some difficult to understand when $f_{n} \in L^{1}$ for all $n$. How I should proceed to verify this point? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have an example of such $f_n$ ? But $f_n\in L^1$ if $\int |f_n|<\infty $ for all $n$. But indeed, to be allowed to write $\int|f_n|$, you must check that $f_n$ is measurable...

Comment: Thank you. Sure, I've edited the question with an example of $f_{n}$.